# Why doesn't echo % do anything in command mode?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, gvim, echo

I read the section of `current-file` in the document. (see `:h current-file`) And I have a question.
if `%` stands for the current file name, why I can not use `echo %`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you found `:help current-file`:

```
As long as you don't write the buffer, the original file remains unchanged.
If you start editing a file (read a file into the buffer), the file name is
remembered as the "current file name".  This is also known as the name of the
current buffer.  It can be used with "%" on the command line :_%.
```

Now, if you follow the tag to `:help :_%`, you get this very helpful paragraph:

```
In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
characters have a special meaning.  These can also be used in the expression
function expand().
```

where the most salient informations seems to be (at this point):

```
at places where a file name can be used
```

Since you want to use `:echo`, the next logical step is to take a look at `:help :echo`, to see if it expects a filename:

```
:ec[ho] {expr1} ..  Echoes each {expr1}, with a space in between. [...]
```

It appears to expect an *expression*, not a filename, so you might want to go back to `:help :_%` with `<C-t>` and re-read that paragraph to see if you missed anything:

```
In Ex commands, at places where a file name can be used, the following
characters have a special meaning.  These can also be used in the expression
function expand().
```

where, now that you are armed with the notion of "expression", the following sentence suddenly makes a lot more sense:

```
These can also be used in the expression function expand()
```

Yes, `:echo` expects an expression and that `expand()` looks promising. From there, you should follow the tag to `:help expand()`, where everything becomes clearer and, frankly, very interesting. One cursory look at that section and a bit of experimenting should allow you to come up with the following in no time:

```
:echo expand('%')
```

And maybe, along the way, you will have noticed that the documentation for every Ex command follows the same pattern:

```
:command_name {type_of_argument}  Yadda-yadda
```

where `{type_of_argument}` instructs you about, well… what type of argument is expected: `{expr}` for expressions, `{file}` for files, etc. This is very helpful.

Now… you might think to yourself "But that's a lot to type, isn't there a better way to print out the current filename?".

Well yes, there are a few, actually.

One is to use `@%` with `:echo`, which is an *expression* that returns the text in register `:help "%`:

```
:echo @%
```

See `:help expr-register`.

Another one is simply to use `:help :file`, which literally exists for that exact purpose:

```
:file
```

Comment: And of course C-g. I've really appreciated this style of answer, which walks through how to understand the docs. Kudos.

Comment: "Teach a man to fish" and all that.

Answer (score 1):

`%` stands for the current filename in most commands but the command parsing depends on the command (`normal`, `map` and `echo` are three command that exemplify that)

The second part of the `echo` command is a vimscript expression.

A rewrite of `echo %` is:

```
:echo expand('%')
```

Comment: I think something somewhere mentions this explicitly. Maybe on help {file}?